# Stuck trying to understand delegates

Tags: c#

book is an object, Namechanged is a field of type delegate, OnNameChange is a method the delegate can point to;OnNameChange simply writes to the console window

With this code:

```
        book.NameChanged = OnNameChange;
        book.NameChanged += OnNameChange;
```

Two instances print out to the screen.

However with this code:

```
        book.NameChanged += OnNameChange;
        book.NameChanged = OnNameChange;
```

Only one instance print out to the screen.Same behavior as this code:

```
        book.NameChanged = OnNameChange;
        book.NameChanged = OnNameChange;
```

Someone please enlighten me about the basics of delegates in C#. I'm still a beginner and gets lost when I try to break and step into the code itself. My weak attempt on explaining the behavior to myself is that if you start a multi-cast delegate, the succeding casts should also be multi-cast.

Any output to help me grasp the concept is much appreciated :D

Comment: A delegate usually refers to a [pointer/reference to a method definition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms173171.aspx) (which also says the method adheres the definition's method signature - i.e. arg types and return type).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose you have

```
const int oneBook = 1;
int bookCounter = 0;
```

Your first code block is equivalent to:

```
// bookCounter == 0
bookCounter = oneBook;
// bookCounter == 1
bookCounter += oneBook;
// bookCounter == 2
```

Your second code block is equivalent to:

```
// bookCounter == 0
bookCounter += oneBook;
// bookCounter == 1
bookCounter = oneBook;
// bookCounter == 1
```

Delegates behave very similarly, but with functions that execute code instead of a number being incremented.

Comment: The answer might be over-simplistic, but I think that's a good way to understand what is happening.

Comment: @ Kobi I am actually a big fan of over-simplistic examples. Thank you for this

Answer (score 2):

Basically the += syntax is resolved to this:

```
book.NameChanged = book.NameChanged + OnNameChange;
```

And the delegate type overrides the + operator creating a MulticastDelegate chaining the method calls. Delegates do support add and subtract as operations to add/substract functions from a invocation list. (As mentioned in the comments the + does not really add a function to the invocation list, instead a new multicast delegate is created for the result).

If you want to suppress the = operator create a event.

```
public event EventHandler NameChanged;
```

Now the = operator is not valid outside the defining class.

Comment: `+=` also creates new delegate because delegates are immutable.